# How to right align text using Core Graphics

Tags: ios, text, core-graphics

I'd like to right align several text when drawing using Core Graphics. Below is the code I'm using to draw text now. How can I draw several texts that are right aligned?

```
CGContextSelectFont(context, "Helvetica-Light", 10.0f,kCGEncodingMacRoman);
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, _privateColor.CGColor);
CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, point.x, point.y, [text cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], text.length);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

perhaps you're looking for something like this...

```
[@"Any text what you like to show" drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 320.f, 80.f) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Light" size:10.f] lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
```

## update

that way is unfortunately deprecated in iOS7+. [source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/drawInRect%3awithFont%3alineBreakMode%3a).

Comment: Thanks. Now that you bring up this solution, I think I'm getting confused on what is Core Graphics and what is Core Text. I think this is Core Text. I guess I don't know if there are rules about mixing this code with Core Graphics code. All my drawing code has been prefixed with "CGContext...". Anyways, that is for me to read up on rather than ask on this post. Thanks for the answer. I like your answers, so please continue to follow my questions... and I'll be sure to vote up your answers.

Comment: @eddieios: No, your code was Core Graphics and holex's is UIKit. You can tell by the prefixes: Core Graphics is CG, UIKit is UI, and [Core Text is CT](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CoreText_Framework_Ref/).

Comment: UILineBreakModeWordWrap is depreciated with iOS 6.

Comment: @MosibAsad, however, it is indeed the values were the exact same.

Answer (score 0):

```
[@"your Text" drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 320.f, 80.f) withAttributes:"dictionary with text attributes"];
```

here the attributes refers to text font,text size,alignment etc.

Where the alignment can be set using the NSMutableParagraphStyle object with the text i.e.lineBreakMode etc